Flutter inkwell becomes unclickable at certain coordinates
I'm building a family tree package for flutter. I've made the tree three nodes deep before you click to expand to see great grandparents. When you click to see great grandparents everything renders correctly but the cards become unclickable, this occurs due to them being at certain coordinates. For an example I've placed one great grandparent below the parent and one great grandparent where it's supposed to be so you can see how the clicking behaves differently at different locations.
Can anyone help me make all of the nodes clickable at any coordinates?

EDIT:
I've figured out the bug, the interactiveViewer is smaller than the child, the child gets rendered when the boundarymargins are large enough but its outside of the interactiveviewer and becomes unclickable, how can i make the child infinitely expandable and have the interactiveviewer pan to the whole child and be clickable
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const FamilyTreeApp());

class FamilyTreeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FamilyTreeApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FamilyTree(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TreeChangeNotifier extends ValueNotifier<void> {
  TreeChangeNotifier() : super(null);

  void notify() => notifyListeners();
}

final treeChangeNotifier = TreeChangeNotifier();

class TreeNode {
  final String name;
  List<TreeNode> parents;
  bool isMale;
  int depth = 0;
  int breadth = 0;
  late ValueNotifier<bool> expanded;

  TreeNode(this.name, {List<TreeNode>? parents, this.isMale = false, bool isExpanded = false}) : parents = parents ?? [] {
    expanded = ValueNotifier(isExpanded)
      ..addListener(() {
        treeChangeNotifier.notify();
      });
    sortParentsByGender();
  }

  void sortParentsByGender() {
    parents.sort((a, b) => (b.isMale ? 1 : 0) - (a.isMale ? 1 : 0));
  }

  void calculateDepth(int currentDepth) {
    depth = currentDepth;
    for (var parent in parents) {
      parent.calculateDepth(currentDepth + 1);
    }
  }

  void calculateBreadthPositions() {
    List<TreeNode> queue = [this];
    Map<int, int> breadthCounter = {};
    while (queue.isNotEmpty) {
      TreeNode current = queue.removeAt(0);
      int currentDepth = current.depth;
      current.breadth = breadthCounter[currentDepth] ?? 0;
      breadthCounter[currentDepth] = current.breadth + 1;
      queue.addAll(current.parents);
    }
  }
}

final TreeNode root = TreeNode(
  'Root',
  isExpanded: false,
  parents: [
    TreeNode(
      'Mother',
      isMale: false,
      parents: [
        TreeNode('Grandmother', isMale: false),
        TreeNode('Grandfather', isMale: true),
      ],
    ),
    TreeNode(
      'Father',
      isMale: true,
      parents: [
        TreeNode('Grandmother', isMale: false),
        TreeNode('Grandfather', isMale: true),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class FamilyTree extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FamilyTreeState createState() => _FamilyTreeState();
}

class _FamilyTreeState extends State<FamilyTree> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Calculate tree dimensions dynamically
    root.calculateDepth(0);
    root.calculateBreadthPositions();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: treeChangeNotifier,
                builder: (context, _, child) {
                  // Dynamically calculate tree size
                  final treeDimensions = calculateTreeDimensions(root);

                  return InteractiveViewer(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      // Use dynamic dimensions for the child
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child: Stack(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                        children: buildTreeNodes(root, Offset.zero),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Size calculateTreeDimensions(TreeNode root) {
  // Define constants for spacing between nodes
  const double depthSpacing = 300; // Adjust as needed for vertical space
  const double breadthSpacing = 200; // Adjust as needed for horizontal space

  // Track the maximum depth and breadth
  double maxDepth = 0;
  double maxBreadth = 0;

  void traverse(TreeNode node) {
    maxDepth = node.depth > maxDepth ? node.depth.toDouble() : maxDepth;
    maxBreadth = node.breadth > maxBreadth ? node.breadth.toDouble() : maxBreadth;
    for (var parent in node.parents) {
      traverse(parent);
    }
  }

  traverse(root);

  // Calculate total width and height needed
  return Size(
    (maxBreadth + 1) * breadthSpacing, // Total width
    (maxDepth + 1) * depthSpacing, // Total height
  );
}

List<Widget> buildTreeNodes(TreeNode node, Offset offset) {
  List<Widget> nodes = [];
  print('NODE: ' + node.name + ', DEPTH: ' + node.depth.toString() + ', BREADTH: ' + node.breadth.toString() + ', EXPANDED: ' + node.expanded.value.toString());

  // Render the root node
  if (node.depth == 0 && node.breadth == 0 && offset == Offset.zero) {
    nodes.add(
      IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: true,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: FamilyTreePainter(node: node),
        ),
      ),
    );
    nodes.add(Positioned(left: 560, top: 330, child: BuildCard(node)));
    for (var parent in node.parents) {
      if (node.expanded.value) {
        offset = Offset((600 * parent.breadth + 270).toDouble(), 150.0);
        nodes.add(Positioned(top: offset.dy, left: offset.dx, child: BuildCard(parent)));
        nodes.addAll(buildTreeNodes(parent, offset));
      }
    }
  }

  if (node.depth == 1) {
    if (node.breadth == 0) {
      nodes.add(
        IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: true,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: FamilyTreePainter(node: node, offset: Offset(-290, -180)),
          ),
        ),
      );
      for (var parent in node.parents) {
        if (node.expanded.value) {
          if (parent.breadth == 0) {
            offset = Offset(-50, -60);
          } else if (parent.breadth == 1) {
            offset = Offset(550, -60);
          }
          nodes.add(Positioned(top: offset.dy, left: offset.dx, child: BuildCard(parent)));
          nodes.addAll(buildTreeNodes(parent, offset));
        }
      }
    } else if (node.breadth == 1) {
      nodes.add(
        IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: true,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: FamilyTreePainter(node: node, offset: Offset(310, -180)),
          ),
        ),
      );
      for (var parent in node.parents) {
        if (node.expanded.value) {
          if (parent.breadth == 2) {
            offset = Offset(600, -60);
          } else if (parent.breadth == 3) {
            offset = Offset(1200, -60);
          }
          nodes.add(Positioned(top: offset.dy, left: offset.dx, child: BuildCard(parent)));
          nodes.addAll(buildTreeNodes(parent, offset));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return nodes;
}

class BuildCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const BuildCard(this.node, {super.key});
  final TreeNode node;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
          valueListenable: node.expanded,
          builder: (context, expanded, child) {
            return OutlinedButton(
              child: Icon(expanded ? Icons.arrow_circle_down : Icons.arrow_circle_up),
              onPressed: () {
                var isOpen = node.expanded.value;

                // Collapse all nodes at the same depth
                void collapseNodes(TreeNode current, int depth) {
                  if (current.depth == depth && current != node) {
                    current.expanded.value = false;
                  }
                  for (var parent in current.parents) {
                    collapseNodes(parent, depth);
                  }
                }

                // Perform collapse for siblings
                if (!isOpen) {
                  collapseNodes(root, node.depth);
                }

                // Toggle the current node's expanded state
                node.expanded.value = !isOpen;

                // Notify to rebuild the tree structure and render updated parents
                treeChangeNotifier.notify();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        Card(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('Tapped: ' + node.name);
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 110,
                width: 60,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Placeholder(
                      fallbackHeight: 60,
                      fallbackWidth: 40,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 6),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          node.name,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FamilyTreePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final TreeNode node; // Track if a node is expanded
  final Offset offset;

  FamilyTreePainter({required this.node, this.offset = Offset.zero});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    if (node.expanded.value) {
      // Horizontal line between Parent 1 and Parent 2
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(310, 220) + offset, Offset(910, 220) + offset, paint);

      // Vertical line from Parent 2 to Child
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(602, 220) + offset, Offset(602, 330) + offset, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true; // Repaint every time
  }
}


I've encountered this as well, IgnorePointer and Inkwell doesn't necessarily work great with each other. Instead of doing this I suggest you work it out the other way around
So instead of having 1 huge listener and making some parts of the ui unclickable. Just make the whole UI clickable but only accept input on specific coordinates.
You can achieve this using the Listener widget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html
For example:
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (PointerDownEvent event) {
    // Position relative to where this widget starts
    Offset tappedLocation = event.localPosition;
    
    // Your hit testing logic here
    // e.g., check if tap coordinates intersect with any nodes
    
    // Handle the tap accordingly
  },
  child: CustomPaint(
    // Your existing CustomPaint implementation
  ),
)


Thanks for the tip, I tried to implement the Listener but it still won't work, I added the code to my original post
